# IntelliJ - ho to remove "create new test" intention when using "goto test"

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a little problem with IntelliJ's intention action when using "goto test" - when you are in test it works ok - it jumps to test derectly. But when you are in class under the test, popup shows asking you whether you wish to go to the test all create new one.
Is there any way to remove this and go directly to the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is by design and you can't disable it. If you feel that you can't live with it, please [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

Comment: I'm very interested as well. Could you share the link to this feature request?